# How to use python NLP POS tagger in C# code?

Tags: c#, python, nlp, pos-tagger

I came across and successfully used a python NLP POS tagger.The problem is that my code was in c# and I used a python pos tagger because I could not find a good c# pos tagger.Now,I don't know how to use this python NLP POS tagger in my c# code.Could anyone guide me?Also please do suggest any C# POS tagger.Thankx

EDIT:
I thought of using IronPython for using the python NLP POS tagger.But when I use `import nltk`,I get an `ImportError:No module named nltk`
The same command when used in python2.6 had worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://www.markwatson.com/opensource/? It appears to list different "parts of speech" taggers implemented in various languages.

Comment: Yes.I did find a C# POS tagger but didn't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) project.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep using the NLP tagger for python, you can always try and host it with the DLR: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/srivatsn/archive/2008/09/16/hosting-ironpython-made-easier.aspx